# StringTokeniser not reading data

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

I've to read data from a file and I've just entered some sample data as a String in StringTokenizer. I can't understand what is wrong with my code here. Can someone please advise?

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class rough {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer("PKE2324 02-12-2020 200"
      + "\nMJD432 19-05-2019 150");

        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()){
            String line = itr.nextToken().toString();
            String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
            String[] date = tokens[1].split("-");
            String yr = date[2];
            String reg = tokens[0];
            String regy = new String(reg + " " + yr);
            System.out.println(regy);   
            }
     }
```

}

I want to get the registration number and year as a String. When I run this, I keep getting ArrayIndexOutofBounds

Comment: Did you debug and see why it is `ArrayIndexOutofBounds`? where exactly are you getting it? Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: @wakanada, kindly see if my answer solves your use case.

Comment: Please include the full stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the type of runtime error which has been caused due to logical error and inappropriate delimeter.

Assuming you want to tokenise the big string using newline character, use, `\n` as delimeter to StringTokenizer.

Have a look at the corrected code below which satisfies your use case:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class rough {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer("PKE2324 02-12-2020 200"
    + "\nMJD432 19-05-2019 150", "\n");

        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()){
            String line = itr.nextToken().toString();
            String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
            String[] date = tokens[1].split("-");
            String yr = date[2];
            String reg = tokens[0];
            String regy = new String(reg + " " + yr);
            System.out.println(regy);   
            }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PKE2324 2020
MJD432 2019
```

Comment: I was actually looking for something else and your answer did give an idea of how to get it. Thanks. I could get it to work without the delim. New to using stringtokenizer.

Answer (score -1):

Exception caused by this line

```
String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
String[] date = tokens[1].split("-");
```

line = PKE2324, so tokens[] = { "PKE2324" } --> length =  1
tokens[1] --> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

To fix this:

```
StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer("PKE2324 02-12-2020 200"
      + "\nMJD432 19-05-2019 150");
```

Default delimeter is whitespace.
You should pass delimeter in constructor if  you want  different delimeter.